# How to padding-top <ion-content> -Ionic 4

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic4

I work with Ionic 4 and the [doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/content) which I refer to, talks about css custom properties;

I tried to add `--padding-top: 100px;` to `/theme/variables.scss` it didn't work.

I want all the `<ion-content>` to have padding-top.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

adding veriables.scss

```
ion-content{
--padding-top: 100px;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just had to  `<ion-content style="--padding-top:100px"></ion-content>`